# How to perform git rebase using LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: libgit2sharp

I am writing a program that manipulates a git repo using the LibGit2Sharp library. One of the operations that I need to perform is a rebase to incorporate changes made to the master into a branch. How do I perform a `git rebase master` command using LibGit2Sharp? I haven't been able to find any examples of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like

```cs
using(var repo = new Repository("path"))
{
    var id = new Identity("name", "email");
    var opt = new RebaseOptions();
    var rebaseResult = repo.Rebase.Start(
            featureBranch,
            masterBranch,
            null,
            id,
            opt);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. I wasn't exactly sure what should go in the third argument, so I'm glad that null is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on dontbyteme but will do a `git pull --rebase`:

```cs
using var gitRepo = new LibGit2Sharp.Repository(r.Path);
            
var remote = r.Network.Remotes["origin"];
var refSpecs = remote.FetchRefSpecs.Select(x => x.Specification);
Commands.Fetch(r, remote.Name, refSpecs, new FetchOptions { Prune = true }, string.Empty);

var id = new Identity("name", "email");
var opt = new RebaseOptions();
var rebaseResult = gitRepo.Rebase.Start(
        branch: gitRepo.Head,
        upstream: gitRepo.Head.TrackedBranch,
        onto: null,
        id,
        opt
        );
```